# Heroku: Angular not loading in Springboot app

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, express, heroku

Locally everything works fine; however I find issues deploying my app to heroku:
my Springboot backend runs but it seems my frontend Angular is not loaded.

on my homepage '/' i get a 404 for my homecall but also for example my icon that is situated in my angular Frontend folder: thats why I think my angular is not loaded.

```
2023-06-22T12:52:21.845842+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com request_id=2dab4af7-f261-4da1-a577-4af911602b49 fwd="84.196.217.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=41ms status=404 bytes=333 protocol=https
2023-06-22T12:52:37.211105+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com request_id=25ad4c19-b2af-408d-a1d0-01e7b470276c fwd="84.196.217.246" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=522 protocol=https
```

also if I hard navigate to an endpoint like /hero/bane I get the expected json result, but not rendered.

```
2023-06-22T12:52:56.240989+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/hero/bane" host=dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com request_id=a8ec1883-0676-4806-b7a4-6f38306ed569 fwd="84.196.217.246" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1349ms status=200 bytes=1007 protocol=https
```

My project structure is like this

```
.mvn/wrapper
Frontend
src
.gitignore
app.json
mvnw
mvnw.cmd
package.json
pom.xml
Procfile
README.MD
server.js
system.properties
```

I deploy my app with my `Procfile` like this

`web: java -jar target/dotaApplicationTool-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=$PORT`

I have Heroku's `heroku/java` and `heroku/nodeJS` buildpacks

my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "ng build --configuration=production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --force --prefix Frontend && npm run build --prefix Frontend"
  },
"private":true, 
"dependencies":{...}
"engines": {
"node": "18.15.0",
"npm": "9.7.2"
}
```

my `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: 'https://dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com'
}));

const distPath = path.join(__dirname, 'Frontend', 'dist', 'frontend');

// Set cache control headers for static files
app.use(express.static(distPath, { setHeaders: (res, filePath) => {
  if (filePath.endsWith('.js') || filePath.endsWith('.css')) {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
  }
}}));

// Define the middleware function
const setJsonContentType = (req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://dota-hero-matchup-cfe3a3ef874f.herokuapp.com');
  next(); // Call next to proceed to the next middleware or route handler
};

// Apply the middleware to all API calls
app.use('/', setJsonContentType);

const host = process.env.HOST ||'0.0.0.0';
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, host, () => {
  console.log('Server is running on port', port);
});
```

my `pom`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>dotaApplicationTool</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>heroMatchupAssistant</name>
    <description>Dota 2 Hero Matchup Assistant</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.moesif.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```